# JPA bad query due to and keyword in parameter of namedquery

Tags: sql, select, jpa, sql-injection, kundera

I am running one select query using named query in JPA by Kundera. Below is the query:

```
"select bff from FileFolder bff where bff.folder_name=:name and bff.usr_id=:usr_id"
```

If I set parameter value to `"test"` it is working fine. However, If I set parameter value to `"test and test"`, then I am getting below error:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: bad jpa query: test'
```

Does anybody have idea how to resolve it?

Comment: Could you post the code of how you set the parameters

Comment: https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/505. As an alternative you may replace "test and test" with "test & test" or "testandtest", till the issue gets fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Vivek for help. Cesar it is bug in Kundera right now.  I am right now replacing with space with some special character until the bug gets resolved.

Reference bug link:

github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/505.